# Angular Form Template One-Way Data Binding

Tags: forms, angular, data-binding

I am attempting to one-way bind to a default value in my HTML form.

My component has a Connection string that is being initialized from local storage:

```js
export class AuthAdminComponent implements OnInit {

  public authenticated = false;
  public connection: String
  public username: string;
  public password: string;
  public token: string;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('adminUser')) {
      let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adminUser'));
      this.connection = data.connection;
      this.username = data.username;
      this.password = data.password;    }
  }
}
```

Then in my form I am attempting to one-way bind to these properties such as connection.  However, it returns [object Object].  I can't seem to figure out how to get the actual value:

```html
<label for="connection">Connection</label>
            <input 
            class="input__username" 
            type="text" 
            name="connection"
            required
            [ngModel]="connection"
            #connection="ngModel" />
            <span *ngIf="!connection.valid && connection.touched">Please enter a valid connection string.</span>
```

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm misunderstanding.  If someone could explain to me what I'm missing, I'd greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: because `connection` is an object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:
You're trying to bind `ngModel` to connection which is a variable defined in your class.
On the other hand you defined `#connection` as a reference variable on the input element.
As a result `ngModel` will bind to this variable and not to the one defined in your class.
One possible solution would be to rename `#connection` to `#connect` (or you can rename `connection` in your class and bind `ngModel` to the renamed variable in your template).
This should fix the problem.